# In firefox, how to change color of text in a treecell using javascript

Tags: javascript, css, firefox, xul

BACKGROUND:
I have the following XUL fragment

```
<tree id="treeToChange" flex="1">
  <treecols>
    <treecol label = "First Column" id="c1" flex="1"/>
    <treecol label = "Second Column" id="c2" flex="1"/>
  </treecols>
  <treechildren>
    <treeitem>
      <treerow>
        <treecell label="Data for Column 1"/>
        <treecell label="Data for Column 2"/>
      </treerow>
    </treeitem>
  </treechildren>
</tree>
```

and the following css fragment

```
tree {  font-size: 120%; color: green;}
```

This causes my column data to be displayed in green text.

I have many such tree objects on the XUL page

QUESTION:
In firefox, in response to a click event, which calls a javascript routine, how do I set the data for the object "treeToChange" in column 1 red and the data in column blue?

Comment: I wonder What makes you think it is ok to call this fragment HTML...

Comment: You are right, it is really an XUL fragment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that the element.style.color only effects the column headings, and that within firefox, the cells in a tree structure can only be affected by coding the dataview.

code snippets follow:

```
// DatabaseTreeView: Create a custom nsITreeView
DatabaseTreeView: function(aTableData, aColumns) {

this.getCellProperties   = function(row,col,props){
var aserv=Components.classes["@mozilla.org/atom-service;1"].getService(Components.interfaces.nsIAtomService);
props.AppendElement(aserv.getAtom("color_"+col.id));
props.AppendElement(aserv.getAtom("font_"+col.id));
};
```

...

and modify the css as follows

```
treechildren::-moz-tree-cell-text(color_c1){ color:DarkGreen}
treechildren::-moz-tree-cell-text(color_c2){ color:Navy}
treechildren::-moz-tree-cell-text(font_c1){ font-size:120%}
treechildren::-moz-tree-cell-text(font_c1){ font-size:150%}
```

I hope this helps someone else in the future

Answer (score 3):

The style property of a DOM element contains all the CSS declarations for that element. The naming scheme is slightly different (camelCaps instead of dashes), but otherwise exactly the same.

```
 element.style.color = 'blue';
```

You can read more on the style property in the [Mozilla javascript manual](http://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/element.style).

Comment: It should be noted that selecting the element can be greatly simplified by using a framework like jQuery which allows you CSS-Style syntax: http://docs.jquery.com/Selectors

Comment: Note:  This does not work on tree cell text, since it is not really part of a DOM element

Comment: This does work on a treecell, similarly to any other DOM element - https://developer.mozilla.org/en/XUL/treecell (read inherited properties at the bottom)

Answer (score 0):

To set the colour of any element, you can use:

```
function changecolour(elid, nc) {
    document.getElementById(elid).style.color = nc;
}
```

So

```
changecolour("c1", "red");
var x = document.getElementsByClassName("cell");
for ( var i = 0; i < x.length; i ++ ) {
    changecolour(x, "blue");
}
```

will change the colour of the data, if you add a cell class to the cells (to avoid conflicting with other trees in the doc)

BTW, [here](http://www.robertnyman.com/2005/11/07/the-ultimate-getelementsbyclassname/) is document.getElementsByClassName:

```
function getElementsByClassName(className, tag, elm){
var testClass = new RegExp("(^|\\s)" + className + "(\\s|$)");
var tag = tag || "*";
var elm = elm || document;
var elements = (tag == "*" && elm.all)? elm.all : elm.getElementsByTagName(tag);
var returnElements = [];
var current;
var length = elements.length;
for(var i=0; i<length; i++){
    current = elements[i];
    if(testClass.test(current.className)){
        returnElements.push(current);
    }
}
return returnElements;
```

}

Comment: Noah is obviously only targets Firefox considering that the fragment is NOT HTML but XUL. So getElementsByClassName is already supported.

Comment: This works well, however I realized that I needed to be a little more specific, since there are many trees on the XUL page.  How do I select only the specific tree I'm working with?  

(Also, you need to move the final } back into the code block )

Comment: Note: This does not work on tree cell text, since it is not really part of a DOM element

Comment: @Noah: Does Firefox have getElementsByClassName in-built? If so, that's a pleasant surprise! :)